# First person camera rotation tilted Unity3d c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**```
I am making a game in which you control a machine gun and attempt to kill enimies. There is no actual player, but only a camera. I needed a first person aspect to the game, so I added some simple script to level 1. If you lose, the level is reset. But, whenever you run it, the cameras rotation gets set off, even though its set to 0,0,0. After you die and respawn, for some reason, the camera is normal and the scene is reset. I also noticed that the camera is at an angle sometimes

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CrosshairMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sens = 100f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform cam;
    float xRotation = 0f;
    float yRotation = 0f;
    public float sceneused = 0f;
    public float currentscene = 0f;
    


    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }


    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sens * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sens * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        yRotation -= mouseX;
        //xRotation -= Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        //transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        cam.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        cam.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Try different gameObject for independent rotation and avoid [gimbal lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno&ab_channel=GuerrillaCG). For this, you can put the camera in the child object, and when parent is rotated in its local axis, the children "suffers" that same rotation.
2. Clamp xrot 180º is usual thing in FPS camera
3. Use `FixedUpdate` only for physics. For anything else use normal `Update`

Suggested snippet with all of the above:

```
public GameObject parentGO; // drag ref to parent go here in the editor    

void Update {
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookAtSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookAtSensitivity * 
    Time.deltaTime;
    xRot -= mouseY;
    xRot = Mathf.Clamp(xRot, -90f, 90f);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, 0f, 0f);
    parentGO.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```